# Why do devices previous to iPhone 5S and iPad Air don't crash when casting a null variable?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I abstracted the code here, since the original is massive:

```
-(void)something {
    // At this point, self.parent is NOT null
    [self boom];
    SomeClass *variable = (SomeClass*)self.parent;
    [variable someMethod];
}

-(void)boom {
    self.parent = nil;
}
```

Surely, if you call `something`, this will crash, because `self.parent` is nullified, and then you attempt to cast it and call a method on it.

So the thing is, this never crashed to me. I mean, for several months, this piece of code has been intact, and my app never crashed.

Now it is crashing for two specific configurations

- iPhone 5S, latest iOS
- iPad Air, latest iOS

All the other previous devices, with the latest iOS too, this didn't crash.

Although the above snippet is not my code, I'm pretty sure it reflects what is happening.

How is this possible? Am I missing something here?

Comment: It shouldn't crash. `variable` should simply be assigned `nil`. What is the error from the crash?

Comment: It's probably worth you completing and then testing the trivial example yourself.

Comment: @rmaddy: The error is `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it back at home.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot a line, which is a method call on the variable. I guess this is the culprit, but I don't understand why doesn't it crash on previous devices.

Comment: It think it's because of the 64 bit processor in iphone 5s and ipad air not sure though.check this http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/64-bit-smorgasbord/.

Comment: This question is not helpful. It's not real code and the posted code doesn't actually crash, does it? The question doesn't point out the error or the line that crashes. Update the question with code that actually crashes and include details about the stack trace and the full error message from the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't doubt you're getting a crash in the real project, but when you factored out the problem to post here (a very admirable practice, by the way, I wish more people would do it), I think you factored out the real source of your crash.

Messaging nil is perfectly fine. Casting happens at compile time, and casting a variable that might be nil at runtime is perfectly fine.

Casting an object to a Bar when it's really a Foo, then invoking a `Bar` method on it will cause an NSInvalidArgumentException (unrecognized selector).

But that's not happening in the OP code.  It's fine for `variable` to be a nil instance of `SomeClass`.  No possible method invocation on it will cause a crash.

Comment: Since `variable` is null, wouldn't `[varialbe someMethod]` effectively crash?

Comment: In Java and Javascript and quite a few others.  But objective-c forgives this... some patterns even encourage it.

Comment: @JustKidding: No. As danh noted in this answer, messaging nil is fine. `[nil someMethod]` is a no-op that returns nil. All messages to nil simply return nil.